# Method now allowed while creating a website with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have just started to learn Flask, and I'm following a tutorial to create a login form, and I'm getting an error while trying to load the website, I'm doing the exact same thing like the guy in the tutorial, I'm running **Ubuntu** and coding in **VS-Code**, why is this happening ?

[Tutorial](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-flask-tutorial/) and the status code of the request is **405**.

**Error: 405 - The method is not allowed for the requested URL.**

**Program:**

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        return 'Hello Boss!'

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def do_admin_login():
    if request.form['password'] == 'password' and request.form['username'] == 'admin':
        session['logged_in'] = True
    else:
        flash('wrong password!')
    return home()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you are trying to access `/login` with a `GET` request. You have 2 options:

- Allow `GET` requests for the `/login` endpoint (which is probably not the best way to solve this):

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
```

- Reach your `/login` endpoint by clicking a `Submit` button or something like that. There should be a form with `action="/login" method="POST"` in your `login.html` and you should use it to reach your endpoint.